# Getting a FrameNode for an instruction (ASM)

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm currently trying to use the ASM tree API to insert a frame in the middle of a method as a future jump target.

I have tried to use the `Analyzer` class in order to compute the stack and variable sizes in a method:

```
Analyzer<BasicValue> analyzer = new Analyzer<>(new BasicInterpreter());
analyzer.analyze(className, methodNode);
Frame<BasicValue>[] frames = analyzer.getFrames();
```

As I understand it, the index of the frame corresponds to the index of the instruction in the method.

My problem is that these frames don't store the information required to create a FrameNode which can be inserted into the method; they just seem to contain the counts of local variables/stack size, but F_FULL requires a full list of all the types and opcodes.

I know the ClassWriter + COMPUTE_FRAMES can solve my problem, but I'm reluctant to use it because I'd have to load the entire classpath for every file I want to  transform. I'm currently hoping this is not my only option, but the ASM javadocs don't seem to have an answer.

Is there any way to create a `FrameNode` for an arbitrary instruction in a method with ASM?

EDIT: Or is there any way to COMPUTE_FRAMES properly without loading the classpath?

Comment: If you can override `String getCommonSuperClass(tring type1, String type2)` in your ClassWriter without resorting to reflection then you can use COMPUTE_FRAMES without worrying about it having to be loaded into the classpath. I did it in a project of mine a while back.

Comment: That's the problem, the classpath is needed to get the common superclass, as hierarchies can go far back into libraries. The implications of returning java/lang/Object are unclear to me, but it seems to violate the method contract at the very least.

Comment: I'll edit the question because using COMPUTE_FRAMES without the classpath is also a solution.

Comment: Well I'll admit my solution used some reflection, but only for loading the bytes of classes already in the classpath (rt.jar). For the classes I was loading I manually created hierarchy structures based on superclasses and interfaces. I then referenced my custom hierarchy in my overriden ClassWriter. Since you only need to compare superclasses and interfaces it's not really that computationally expensive to make the hierarchy when you initially load the jar file into your program. Mine only had a 100 ms startup delay when throwing in a 8 Mb jar file.

Comment: I believe a problem arises when the JAR file in question references classes outside of rt.jar, e.g. if it's a plugin to something.

Comment: It’s not clear, what you hope to achieve with the `Analyzer`. It hasn’t any magic way to determine the common super class of two classes without loading them.

Comment: The analyzer doesn't seem to need them to compute frames... what am I missing here?

Comment: `Analyzer.getFrames()` does not promise to return frames suitable for `StackMapTable` entries (like `COMPUTE_FRAMES` delivers). Its result depends on the `Interpreter` you pass in and `BasicInterpreter` is what its name suggests, a very basic interpreter. As you noticed already yourself, “these frames don't store the information required to create a `FrameNode`”, which explains, why it doesn’t need the `getCommonSuperClass` method. If you would like to track the actual types, you would have to subclass it and override `newValue` and `merge`, which brings you back to square one.

Comment: To make it short, there is no way to tell the relationship between two different types without knowing these types (or well, their relationship). • But you should rethink your requirement. You want to instrument code by inserting a branch into it. You should have some knowledge about the code you are instrumenting, shouldn’t you? So instead of tracing the entire method, you may use the existing frames and your knowledge about what you are actually doing to the code to define the target’s frame.

Comment: That sounds like a much simpler solution, thank you.